# python curses, how to use control, shift keys?

Tags: python, python-curses

I am currently making a python project in curses, I want to know how to use the control and shift keys using stdscr.getch(), the other keys work, except for a few keys including ctrl and shift.

The code for the files look like this

```py
# script_1.py

import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(False)
curses.start_color()
stdscr.keypad(True)
curses.mousemask(True)
```

```py
# script_2.py

from script_1 import *

cmd = stdscr.getch()

if cmd == curses.KEY_CONTROL_L:
    print("You pressed Left Control")   # This code won't work

elif cmd == curses.KEY_SHIFT_L:
    print("You pressed Left Shift")     # This code won't work
```

Comment: There is no such key in curses

Comment: @ShadowGunn I checked and those keys exist.

Comment: Okay I could not find them

Comment: Have you tried using getkey() instead of .getch()? https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getkey

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work

Comment: so what is the error that it gives you? Also, could you send the link where they exist?

Comment: It doesn't give an error, the keys just don't work.